# Which css parameter modifies animate('width', 'hide') function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my jquery function, I have few elements in ul list, some of them are shown, and some of them not. After clicking a li item, I want to check, if there is anything shown, hide it (by sliding it to the left), and perform another action (but only if first function was performed!). So how can I check, if that first action was performed (element was animated by jquery)?
HTML code looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
     <div class="content_nav content_nav1">
     </div>
     <div class="content_el content_el1"> 
     </div>
</li>
<li>
     <div class="content_nav content_nav2">
     </div>
     <div class="content_el content_el2"> 
     </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery:

```
for ( var i=1; i<3; i++)
    {
        if (i != item_number)
        {
             var another_content = ".content_el" + i;
             var another_nav = ".content_nav" + i;

             $(another_content).animate({'width': 'hide'}, animate_duration);
              //here i want to check, if action above was performed
                 $(another_nav).animate({'width':'show'}, animate_duration);
                    }
            }
```

I would be grateful for any help!
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
So, the right question is, which css parameter

```
  $(another_content).animate({'width': 'hide'}, animate_duration);
```

modifies.

Answer (score 0):

the animate function comes with a 'complete' handler.
https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Run your function like this:

```
$(another_content).animate({'width': 'hide'} , animate_duration, function(){
    $(another_nav).animate({'width':'show'}, animate_duration);
})
```

EDIT:
The animate function is always "performed" so you need to check if the element is visible to begin width:

```
if($(another_content).is(":visible")){
    $(another_content).animate({'width': 'hide'} , animate_duration, function(){
        $(another_nav).animate({'width':'show'}, animate_duration);
    })
}
```

Comment: But then, `$(another_nav).animate({'width':'show'}, animate_duration);` will be executed for each element, even if it's already hidden, because the function `$(another_content).animate({'width': 'hide'} , animate_duration, function(){` will do nothing and proceed. I want to know which css parameter should I check for change. (sorry, english is not my native)

Comment: You can't do it at that time, but you can make the check before you begin the animation. Check my update

Comment: So, `animate({'width':'hide'})` modifies the `visibility` parameter? It doesn't seems so, as I exexute `alert($(another_nav).css("visibility"));` before and after execution, and it stays the same: 'visible'.

Answer (score 0):

If i uderstand your question correctly,

You can pass a function to show `another_nav` only ofter `another_content` finished animating

```
$(another_content).animate({width: 'hide'}, animate_duration, function () {
   $(another_nav).animate({width:'show'}, animate_duration);
)};
```